# Firebase prepare the data before loading into recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

I am implementing a chat feature in my app. I have used 2 activities for that a (ChatRoom activity) and (ChatActivity).

**ChatRoom Activity**

this will be the activity that shows the chat rooms.

**Chat Activity**

this will be the activity that shows the chat messages, which means the activity that is started upon clicking a chat room.

**MY PROBLEM**

I use child listener to grab the messages, and a recycler view to show them. This works fine.

But the problem is that when the (ChatActivity) starts it takes about 3 sec delay to properly show the data.

In other words: The data doesn't show up properly before 3 seconds, but after 3 second the data shows up.

**The case in the common chat apps**

In the common used chat apps, when you click the chatroom the data is just there (no loading progress & no splash screens).

**What do I know and what do I think**

1) I know that firebase have what is called by keeping a node synced that should keep a node synced and updated on disk.

used like this:

```
  reference.keepSynced(true);
```

and also I know that firebase reads from disk before reading from server.

2) I think that most chat apps prepare the data before you click on the chat room, so you find it just there (no loading).

Any suggestion on how to go about this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

If you don't want to have this 3seconds delay you might what to consider prefetching the chats while the chat room is loading and passing the data to the chat activity.

Solution 2

Save chart history using an offline database like room or realm and fetch the chat from there while the one from firebase is loading and merge the data when its loaded.

Comment: and how do you go about the prefetching, thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is not really a good solution for large data but it works, prefetch in this sense is getting the chat data while the user is still in the chat room.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, but as you know a chat data is continuous so it tends to become very large overtime, so if I do fetch the data in chat room activity. Then what is the guarantee that the data is already prepared?

Comment: The load time of the chat room will be dependent on when the chats are loaded, so in that case you are sure you have all the data you need.

Comment: is ( ref.keepSynced(true) ) responsible for downloading the data to the disk? and should I do ( ref.keepSynced(true) ) in the chat room activity?

Comment: keepSynced(true) is used for offline access which means firebase will save the data to disk so that on an event whereby network access is not available it will load the previously saved data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160012/discussion-between-kuti-gbolahan-and-svi-data).